# PowerShell setting environment variable to subexpression discards newline

Tags: python, windows, powershell, terminal

I have a python script:

```py
# temp.py
print("foo\nbar")
```

I can run this in powershell:

```
> python .\temp.py
foo
bar
```

I want to set the environment variable `FOO` to the output of this python script. However, doing so changes the newline to a space:

```
> $env:FOO=$(python .\temp.py)
> $env:FOO
foo bar
```

### What I've Tried

Verify that environment variables can contain newlines:

```
> echo "foo`nbar"
foo
bar
> $env:FOO2=$(echo "foo`nbar")
> $env:FOO2
foo
bar
```

... so it seems like the issue has something to do with execution of a python script?

Verify that the subexpression operator `$()` is not modifying the python script output:

```
> $(python .\temp.py)
foo
bar
```

`echo`ing the output of the python script seems to exhibit the same behavior:

```
> echo "$(python .\temp.py)"
foo bar
```

... but not if I exclude the quotes:

```
> echo $(python .\temp.py)
foo
bar
```

### Workaround

Base64 encoding the string bypasses bypasses this issue. However, I still wonder what could be causing this?

My powershell version is 5.1.22621.963

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$env:FOO = (python .\temp.py) -join "`n"
```

- PowerShell reports stdout output from external programs such as `python` *line by line*, which, when captured via `$(...)` or `(...)`, results in an *array* of lines (for two or more lines).
- If you try to assign the result *as-is* to an environment variable - which is invariably *string*-typed - PowerShell *implicitly  stringifies the array*, which means that it joins its elements with a *space* as the separator, so that lines `foo` and `bar` turn into a string with verbatim content `foo bar`; that is, the *newlines are replaced with spaces*.
- By explicitly joining the elements with a (LF-only) newline (expressed as `` "`n" `` via an [expandable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) PowerShell string) using the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join) operator, an explicit multi-line string is constructed up front, which can then be assigned to an environment variable.

Comment: Ah ok, good ol' type coercion. So I was trying to set an environment variable to an array, which it coerced to a string. Thanks for the explanation!